# mongodb how to combine aggregate and $regex in a query

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I want to run a query which shows the selected information but also prints a blank line if there are no details associated with a detail.  Eg.  The following will show the id, name, address and age of customers along with their rankings (where they have rankings) based on their address.  But if one customer has a ranking and the other doesnt then I get an error message.  Would I use a aggregate and $project instead and if so, where go I place the $project. Thank you

```
    with MongoClient() as client:
        db = client.get_database("test")
        coll = db.get_collection("info")
        for col in coll.find({"cust.address": { "$regex":address}}):
          print (col["_id"] , ":",  col["cust"]["name"],":",  col["cust"]["age"], col["ranking"] )
```

Comment: Enter Address : Turin
G0012 : John X : 21 ['ARTS', 'DATA']     This is where there is only one from Turin                
Enter Address : Dubai                                                                                                                           
print (col["_id"] , ":",  col["cust"]["name"],":",  col["cust"]["age"], col["ranking"], )
KeyError: 'ranking'                                                                                                  Is what comes up if I type in Dubai and there are two customers, one has a ranking and the other does not.

Comment: Where are you getting this error ? Is it in the query or in the print statement ? How does your input look like & can you provide sample docs ?

Comment: The error comes after I run the query

Comment: Apologies if I am not explaining myself very clearly.

Comment: Ok issue with query can you edit question with input(`address`)  & sample docs..